# SQL Argument data type datetime is invalid for argument 1 of substring function

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to run an sql query to move data from one table into another but I'm having trouble. Here is my query:

```
TRUNCATE TABLE LIQ_ACCT_EOD_SIF

DECLARE @filedt varchar(32), @repdate int;
SET NOCOUNT ON


SET @filedt = CAST(getdate() as varchar);

select @repdate=CAST(right(S_ReportingDate, 4) + SUBSTRING(S_ReportingDate,4,2) + LEFT(S_ReportingDate, 2)
AS int)
FROM AllocationJunLLv2;

DELETE FROM dbo.LIQ_ACCT_EOD_SIF
WHERE REPORT_DATE=@repdate;


INSERT INTO dbo.LIQ_ACCT_EOD_SIF
(
 FILE_NUM
,FILE_DATE_TIME
,ROW_NUM
,FILE_TYPE
,MIGRATION_DATE
,INSTITUTION_NAME
,RESULT_TYPE_NAME
,SCENARIO_NAME
,REPORT_DATE
,ASSET_CLASS_NAME
,INSTRUMENT_TYPE_NAME
,INSTRUMENT_SUBTYPE_NAME
,INSTRUMENT_NAME
,COUNTERPARTY_NAME
,CORPORATE_RETAIL_FLG
,CLIENT_NAME
,DEPOSIT_FLG
,POSITION_FLG
,LIQUID_FLG
,LOCATION_NAME
,PORTFOLIO_NAME
,ACCOUNT_TYPE_NAME
,ACCOUNT_NUMBER
,ACCOUNT_OPENING_DATE
,INSTRUMENT_ISO_CURRENCY
,ISO_CURRENCY_CODE
,CURRENT_VALUE
,MATURITY_DATE
,MATURITY_VALUE
,DRAWN_AMOUNT
,UNDRAWN_AMOUNT
,LIMIT_AMOUNT
,EXPOSURE_CD
,EXPECTED_CASH_FLOW
,EXPECTED_CASH_FLOW_DATE
,PASSED_DUE_IND
,INT_TYPE
,INT_FIXED_RATE
,INT_VAR_BASENAME
,INT_REL_VAR_RATE
,RATING_NAME
,RATING_AGENCY
,BASEL_OPTION
,RATING_TYPE
,REPORT_LINE_NUMBER
,REPORT_LINE_NAME
,DELTA
,GAMMA
,NETTING_NUMBER
,COLLATERAL_ACCOUNT_NUMBER
,BUFFER_ELIGIBLE
,ALTERNATIVE_YIELD_RATE
,FTP_PORTFOLIO
,REPO_FLAG
,LIMIT_EXPIRY_DATE
,AL_DEFINITION
,REPO_AMOUNT
,TRANSACTION_NUMBER
,UNENCUMBERED_AMOUNT
,MARGIN_ACCOUNT_NUMBER
,CASH_FLOW_TYPE
,value_of_house
,security_value
,security_type
,int_rate_floor
,int_rate_ceiling
,lcr_line_number
,AMM_line_number
,BASEL_APPROACH
,CCR_portfolio
,CCR_sector
,CCR_region
)

SELECT
 1 AS FILE_NUM
,@filedt AS FILE_DATE_TIME
,0 AS ROW_NUM
,'EOD' AS FILE_TYPE
,getdate() AS MIGRATION_DATE    
,'UBNL' AS INSTITUTION_NAME 
,LEFT(b.STBITEM, 32) AS RESULT_TYPE_NAME
,'Unknown' AS SCENARIO_NAME
,@repdate AS REPORT_DATE
,ISNULL(rl.ASSET_CLASS_NAME, 'Unknown') AS ASSET_CLASS_NAME
,'Unknown' AS INSTRUMENT_TYPE_NAME
,'Unknown' AS INSTRUMENT_SUBTYPE_NAME
,'Unknown' AS INSTRUMENT_NAME
,LEFT(b.S_InstitutionCode, 32) AS COUNTERPARTY_NAME
,ISNULL(rl.CORPORATE_RETAIL_FLG, 'U')
,b.S_CustomerName AS CLIENT_NAME
,'U' AS DEPOSIT_FLG
,'U' AS POSITION_FLG
,'U' LIQUID_FLG
,'Unknown' AS LOCATION_NAME
,b.S_Ref1 AS PORTFOLIO_NAME
,'Unknown' AS ACCOUNT_TYPE_NAME
,b.Unique_ID AS ACCOUNT_NUMBER
,CAST( right(CAST(S_StartDate AS varchar(8)),4) + SUBSTRING(CAST(S_StartDate AS varchar(8)),4,2) + LEFT(CAST(S_StartDate AS varchar(8)), 2)AS int) 
AS ACCOUNT_OPENING_DATE

,'USD' AS INSTRUMENT_ISO_CURRENCY
,'USD' AS ISO_CURRENCY_CODE
,CASE
    WHEN rl.CURRENT_VALUE_FLG='Y' THEN 
    CAST(CAST(CASE dbo.udf_ExtractChars(S_FormValue, '^0-9.E-') WHEN '-' THEN '0' ELSE dbo.udf_ExtractChars(S_FormValue, '^0-9.E-') END AS float) AS numeric(22,6)) * fx.EXCHANGE_RATE
    ELSE 0
 END AS CURRENT_VALUE
,ISNULL(CAST( right(S_MaturityDate,4) + SUBSTRING(S_MaturityDate,4,2) + LEFT(S_MaturityDate, 2)AS int), 29991231) AS MATURITY_DATE
,CASE
    WHEN rl.MATURITY_VALUE_FLG='Y' THEN
    CAST(CAST(CASE dbo.udf_ExtractChars(S_FormValue, '^0-9.E-') WHEN '-' THEN '0' ELSE dbo.udf_ExtractChars(S_FormValue, '^0-9.E-') END AS float) AS numeric(22,6)) * fx.EXCHANGE_RATE
    ELSE 0
 END AS MATURITY_VALUE
,0 AS DRAWN_AMOUNT
,CASE
    WHEN rl.UNDRAWN_AMOUNT_FLG='Y' THEN 
    CAST(CAST(CASE dbo.udf_ExtractChars(S_FormValue, '^0-9.E-') WHEN '-' THEN '0' ELSE dbo.udf_ExtractChars(S_FormValue, '^0-9.E-') END AS float) AS numeric(22,6)) * fx.EXCHANGE_RATE
    ELSE 0
 END AS UNDRAWN_AMOUNT
,CASE
    WHEN rl.LIMIT_AMOUNT_FLG='Y' THEN 
    CAST(CAST(CASE dbo.udf_ExtractChars(S_FormValue, '^0-9.E-') WHEN '-' THEN '0' ELSE dbo.udf_ExtractChars(S_FormValue, '^0-9.E-') END AS float) AS numeric(22,6)) * fx.EXCHANGE_RATE
    ELSE 0
 END AS LIMIT_AMOUNT
,ISNULL(rl.EXPOSURE_CD, 'Unknown') AS EXPOSURE_CD
,CASE
    WHEN rl.EXPECTED_CASH_FLOW_FLG='Y' THEN 
    CAST(CAST(CASE dbo.udf_ExtractChars(S_FormValue, '^0-9.E-') WHEN '-' THEN '0' ELSE dbo.udf_ExtractChars(S_FormValue, '^0-9.E-') END AS float) AS numeric(22,6)) * fx.EXCHANGE_RATE
    ELSE 0
 END AS EXPECTED_CASH_FLOW
,CASE
    WHEN rl.EXPECTED_CASH_FLOW_FLG='Y' THEN ISNULL(CAST( right(S_MaturityDate,4) + SUBSTRING(S_MaturityDate,4,2) + LEFT(S_MaturityDate, 2)AS int), 29991231) 
    ELSE 0
 END AS EXPECTED_CASH_FLOW_DATE
,'U' AS PASSED_DUE_IND
,'U' AS INT_TYPE
,0 AS INT_FIXED_RATE
,'Unknown' AS INT_VAR_BASENAME
,0 AS INT_REL_VAR_RATE
,'Unknown' AS RATING_NAME
,'Unknown' AS RATING_AGENCY
,'B2L' AS BASEL_OPTION
,'LT' AS RATING_TYPE
,ISNULL(CAST(SUBSTRING(b.STBITEM, 5, 2) AS int), 0) AS REPORT_LINE_NUMBER
,ISNULL(rl.REPORT_LINE_NAME, 'Unknown') AS REPORT_LINE_NAME
,0 AS DELTA
,0 AS GAMMA
,'Unknown' AS NETTING_NUMBER
,'Unknown' AS COLLATERAL_ACCOUNT_NUMBER
,'U' AS BUFFER_ELIGIBLE
,0 AS ALTERNATIVE_YIELD_RATE
,'Unknown' AS FTP_PORTFOLIO
,'U' AS REPO_FLAG
,0 AS LIMIT_EXPIRY_DATE
,ISNULL(rl.AL_DEFINITION, 'U') AS AL_DEFINITION
,0 AS REPO_AMOUNT
,'Unknown'AS TRANSACTION_NUMBER
,0 AS UNENCUMBERED_AMOUNT
,'Unknown' AS MARGIN_ACCOUNT_NUMBER
,CASE
    WHEN rl.REPORT_LINE_NUMBER BETWEEN 6 AND 17 THEN 7
    WHEN rl.REPORT_LINE_NUMBER=23 THEN 6
    ELSE 1
 END AS CASH_FLOW_TYPE
,0 as value_of_house
,0 as security_value
,'Unknown' as security_type
,0 AS INT_RATE_FLOOR
,0 AS INT_RATE_CEILING
,'Unk' as LCR_LINE_NUMBER
,'Unk' as AMM_LINE_NUMBER
,'Unknown' as basel_approach
,'Unknown' as CCR_portfolio
,'Unknown' as CCR_sector
,'Unknown' as CCR_region
FROM AllocationJunLLv2 b

INNER JOIN LIQ_EXCH_RATE_SIF fx ON 'USD'=fx.SOURCE_CURRENCY_CD
INNER JOIN DM_REPORT_LINE rl 
ON CAST(SUBSTRING(b.STBITEM, 5, 2) AS int)=rl.REPORT_LINE_NUMBER AND rl.REPORT_NUMBER=48
 WHERE ISNULL(CAST(CAST(
  CASE dbo.udf_ExtractChars(S_FormValue, '^0-9.E-') WHEN '-' THEN '0' ELSE   dbo.udf_ExtractChars(S_FormValue, '^0-9.E-') END
  AS float)
  AS numeric(22,6))
, 0) <> 0
AND NOT (
LEFT(b.STBITEM, 3) = 'F48' AND 
RIGHT(b.STBITEM, 2) = 'C1' AND 
CAST(SUBSTRING(b.STBITEM, 5, 2) AS int) BETWEEN 6 AND 17
)


UPDATE LIQ_ACCT_EOD_SIF
SET 
    CURRENT_VALUE=-CURRENT_VALUE,
    MATURITY_VALUE=-MATURITY_VALUE
WHERE
    REPORT_DATE=@repdate

GO
```

The errors I'm getting are:

```
Msg 8116, Level 16, State 1, Line 9
Argument data type datetime is invalid for argument 1 of substring function.
Msg 8116, Level 16, State 1, Line 17
Argument data type datetime is invalid for argument 1 of substring function.
```

Now I've tried

```
CAST(S_ReportingDate as nvchar(8))
```

but that didn't fix the problem, does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: I removed the mysql tag, because the syntax looks like SQL Server.

Comment: You get this error because you try to run string operators on a date format. You should use something like `FORMAT(S_ReportingDate,'YYYYMMDD')` or `CONVERT(S_ReportingDate,112)` if you do not have the .NET extension: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx

Comment: @AHocevar what extension are you referring to?  Is it part of SSMS or VS?

Comment: It's part of the CLR, I haven't used it so far. According to the documentation, you need SQL Server 2014 or later
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213505.aspx

Comment: @AHocevar I am a little confused since you mentioned an extension (something added on) and you keep linking MSDN pages that are included features of SQL Server.  I thought you meant something you download for SSMS or VS.

Comment: I was referring to an extension for the support of `FORMAT()` as I overlooked the documentation. But you're right, they are native features of SQL Server, it should work out of the box.

Answer (score 5):

SUBSTRING() function accepts character data types like char, varchar, nchar, nvarchar, text etc.

If we pass, a DATETIME datatype, it doesn't know what to do.

the values of it are formatted like 2015-01-13 00:00:00.000, but they are not. This is just the standard format of the connection that makes the datetime value readable. You can use the CONVERT function with a suitable format number to convert your datetime to a string. If you only need the date part of the datetime, then my preferred format is 112, which format it as YYYYMMDD.

In other words, just pass "CONVERT(char(8), date, 112)" to your substring function.

If you also need the time part, then check Books Online for a more appropriate format.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are trying to extract the year, month, and date out of a datetime field using string operations.  You can do a simple convert on datetime fields to the appropriate format:

```
CONVERT (varchar(15), GETDATE(), 112)
```

If you need it as an `INT`, then just wrap that in another `CONVERT(int)` function.

Comment: I've tried your suggestion and changed it to `CAST(CONVERT (varchar(15), S_ReportingDate, 112) AS INT)` however I'm still getting this error: `Msg 8116, Level 16, State 1, Line 42
Argument data type datetime is invalid for argument 1 of substring function.`
Line 42 corresponds to: `INSERT INTO dbo.LIQ_ACCT_EOD_SIF`

Comment: It looks like you do the same stuff in the `INSERT` as well.  Go through each line and replace your `SUBSTRING`s with the new `CONVERT` logic.