# The conversion of a nvarchar data type to a smalldatetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I've a  SQL query which looks like :

```
select LAST_UPDATED from Employees WHERE (CAST(LAST_UPDATED AS smalldatetime)) > (CAST('@updateTime' AS smalldatetime))

command.Parameters.AddWithValue("updateTime", updatedTime);
```

I went through several of the related questions asked here and also [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver15) but none could solve my issue.

I also tried the ***ISO-8601 format*** for dates (YYYYMMDD) which also doesn't seem to work here.

The data type of LAST_UPDATED column in SQL server is DATE.

The problem is like this works well in development machine and in SQL management studio but throws the following error in Test server:

> The conversion of a nvarchar data type to a smalldatetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value

SQL management studio query:

```
select LAST_UPDATED from Employees WHERE (CAST(LAST_UPDATED AS smalldatetime)) > (CAST('2014-08-10 ' AS smalldatetime))
```

It would be very helpful if someone can put some light on this.

Comment: Are you writing the variable name as literal instead of an actual variable?

Comment: You're trying to convert the string `'@updateTime'` to a smalldatetime - not the value of the `@updateTime` variable.

Comment: Instead of `AddWithValue` I recommend use `Parameters.Add` and defining the datatype of your input parameter in your C# code.

Comment: Can you include how you are assigning the variable `updatedTime` value in C#? Might be some date dependent OS settings thats formatting the date that makes SQL Server fail when converting.

Comment: @EzLo : Thanks to you, issue was in the way `updatedTime` was being assigned!

Answer (score 1):

Ahh!Finally the issue is solved. I was assigning `string updatedTime` like this:

```
string updatedTime = strUpdateTime.Substring(0, 11);
string strUpdateTime = GetLastUpdate()
```

So what my code looked like is:

```
string strUpdateTime = GetLastUpdate()
string updatedTime = strUpdateTime.Substring(0, 11);

select LAST_UPDATED from Employees WHERE (CAST(LAST_UPDATED AS smalldatetime)) > (CAST('@updateTime' AS smalldatetime))

command.Parameters.AddWithValue("updateTime", updatedTime);
```

And while searching an answer for post I came accross [Mike Clark's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31809046/sql-argument-data-type-datetime-is-invalid-for-argument-1-of-substring-function) and noticed that I've also used Substring(). So instead of passing `updatedTime` I passed `strUpdateTime`

```
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("updateTime", strUpdateTime);
```

If one needs to change the format of DateTime it can be done in [several ways](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) .

Thanks to everyone who has contributed to this post.

Comment: I'm glad you found an answer. Next time, try to include ***all*** the relevant code so we avoid ping-pong Q&A since this time the error was outside the code you included in your post.

Comment: @EzLo Sure, will do that.

Answer (score 0):

Check out these examples:

```
DECLARE @updateTime VARCHAR(20) = '2020-01-01'

SELECT CAST('@updateTime' AS smalldatetime)
```

> Msg 295, Level 16, State 3, Line 3 Conversion failed when converting
>   character string to smalldatetime data type.

Now if we remove the single quotes, we will actually access the content of the variable and not the hard-coded string `'@updateTime'`:

```
DECLARE @updateTime VARCHAR(20) = '2020-01-01'

SELECT CAST(@updateTime AS smalldatetime)
```

Result:

```
2020-01-01 00:00:00
```

Single quotes are used to delimit literal values. You can access a variable's content with their name (starting with the `@`), without any quotes.

---

If the problem is actually the `LAST_UPDATED` contents, then replace your forced `CAST` for a `TRY_PARSE`, which won't fail if the `LAST_UPDATED` content isn't convertible.

```
select LAST_UPDATED from Employees 
WHERE TRY_PARSE(LAST_UPDATED AS smalldatetime) > TRY_PARSE(@updateTime AS smalldatetime)
```

Comment: Tried your suggestion still getting the same error, am I missing out something silly!

Comment: If `Last_Updated` is already a date, then the problem is with the C# variable's value.

Answer (score 0):

Like I said in the comments, don't pass an `nvarchar`, pass a date parameter, and then you don't need to cast it. So in your c# instead do:

```
command.Parameters.Add("updateTime",SqldbType.DateTime).Value = updatedTime
```

Then your SQL can be as simple as:

```
SELECT LAST_UPDATED
FROM Employees
WHERE LAST_UPDATED > @updateTime;
```

*Assuming, of course, that `LAST_UPDATED` is a `(small)datetime`; but then,* why *wouldn't it be if it's being compared as a Date?*

Comment: Your suggestion seems to be making more sense but when I tried the same I get error as **String was not recognized as a valid DateTime** 

I felt this is due to the `updatedTime` variable of being `String` data-type, So I did

`DateTime time = Convert.ToDateTime(updatedTime);`
                    `command.Parameters.Add("updatetime",SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = time;`

Value of `time` is `2014-08-10 00:00:00`

and now I'm getting the error as **String was not recognized as a valid DateTime**

I feel I'm missing out something very very silly!

Comment: `updatedTime` would need to be a date and time data type in your application. Why isn't it, @m_beta ?

Comment: That's existing code, lets not get into that part.
But here as u can see I did convert `updatedTime` to `DateTime` data-type.